# I produce double the values while using group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a task to make a query that shows the ID of a project, how many hours have been worked on it and how many hours have been paid.

I am using this SQL statement:

```sql
select t.project_id,sum(t.hours) 
from time t 
    JOIN bills b on t.project_id = b.project_id 
where marked = "P" 
GROUP by t.project_id
```

I worked 16 hours on the project with id 1. I have 2 bills, one for each 8 hours.

My query now results in: sum(t.hours)*amount of bills.

The result I want in this case is:

```
1, 16
```

I get

```
1, 32
```

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: I suspect that every `time` record you have two or more `bills` records? Do a `SELECT *` and remove the `GROUP BY` to confirm. That result set is what you are aggregating in this `sum` and since there are two records in that result set with `t.hours` value of `16` you get `32` when you sum. If you can provide sample data and desired results we can likely help write the SQL you need.

Comment: You need to sum the bills before joining to time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.project_id, 
       SUM(t.hours) 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM time 
      GROUP BY project_id) t
JOIN bills b ON t.project_id = b.project_id 
WHERE marked = "P"
```